# Can we convert existing React Native app to flutter without writing the code from scratch in flutter

Tags: react-native, flutter

I have a existing react native application . Can i migrate  it to flutter without starting the application from scratch in flutter.
Thanks.

Comment: Nope, you can't. React-native is from Facebook, flutter is from Google. It's 101% in different. I dont think they want to make it able to convert  from their framework into their comparative company framework

Answer (score 4):

Yes, to a certain degree.

This tool can convert React Native components to Flutter Widgets:

https://github.com/GeekyAnts/react-native-to-flutter

And this can convert JavaScript to Dart (though it is very old, so may not work with recent versions):

https://github.com/luisvt/jsparser

This does the same for TypeScript and is significantly newer *and* appears to be used to convert Angular to Dart, so should work on just about any codebase... But it has been archived, so it's future is unclear!

https://github.com/dart-archive/ts2dart

Ultimately after you've done any kind of automatic conversion you'll still have a fair bit to go, some things will be broken horribly, some will work, but the automated conversation can write some very odd and verbose code.

I know this question is fairly old, but the existing answers just felt a little defeatist! So hopefully this is of some use to someone, please comment if things don't work or you know of better tools!

Answer (score -2):

You can't. React Native and Flutter are different frameworks.

Comment: If they were the same framework, it wouldn't be converting, would it?
Converting between any two wildly different things is almost always possible, someone just needs to care about doing it enough.
If you should or not is another question, there will always be drawback, but in the right situation it's worth it!

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. The widget generator that you've shared is interesting. That should help with creating their app from React to Flutter or help to at least make their app visually similar. I don't want to sound negative, but they'll still be coding from scratch other than that they've had a head-start on the generated widgets. Also, more often than not, libraries that they've used on React might have an equivalent on Flutter. There's just no way to "convert" their app to Flutter easily. With that amount of effort, it might be more beneficial to create the Flutter app from scratch.